# javascript function from php like html href

Tags: php, javascript

I am calling the javascript function from another file in href, I want to know if there is any way to call it in php without using href?

call from href

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:NewCal()">Link1</a>
```

how can I use "javascript:NewCal()" in PHP echo?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think you should simply be able to `echo "<script>NewCal();</script>";`. If you want to do this after page load, however, you'll want to look into [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP can't directly call a Javascript function because PHP runs on the server side and Javascript on the client.

What you can do is echo the Javascript call into an `onclick` handler or any other event handler for example:

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="javascript:NewCal()">Link1</a>';
    echo '<p onclick="NewCal()">Click me</p>';
?>
```

If you want to execute it on load:

```
echo '<script>window.onload = function(){ NewCal(); };</script>';
```

Comment: I need to call this function without user, if I use <a href> user need to click on that

Comment: See my example of calling it on load.

Answer (score 2):

```
 echo '<a href="javascript:NewCal()">Link1</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

`echo "<a href=\"javascript:NewCal();\">";`

Comment: or just `echo '<a href="javascript:NewCal();">';`

Answer (score -1):

yes you can cal function like:

```
    <a href = "#"> <spam name="spmNewCal" onclick="javascript:NewCal()" id="spmNewCal" /></a>
```